# Alternative to CCLocationManager's deprecated purpose field

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone help me solve this error:

> purpose is deprecated

What can I do to make this work?

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {

  if (_locationManager != nil) {
    return _locationManager;
  }

  _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
  _locationManager.delegate = self;
  _locationManager.purpose = @"Your current location is used to demonstrate PFGeoPoint and Geo Queries.";

  return _locationManager;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in case if you are not able to find it on google**

iOS 6 deprecated the purpose property and it now has to be set in your `Info.plist` with the key `NSLocationUsageDescription` which is displayed in Xcode as Privacy - Location Usage Description. If you're still supporting iOS 5 and earlier make sure you include both.